# .NET Real Time Email Notifications From Web App

Tags: c#, .net, email, azure, real-time

I have an web application which runs on [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and is hosted in [[image]azure](/questions/tagged/azure). We allow out clients to set reminders / alerts which then get emailed to them after they login.

How do we turn this into a real time service. IE: Automatically send the emails at the times set in the db. In the past I would have used a windows service, but I am not quite sure where to start looking at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to run the db-checking and emailing task in an Azure WebJob: [Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs)

With Azure Webjobs you could either make background tasks run on demand or at a set interval throug the websjob scheduler.

A few more links to get you started:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a5470d/creating-and-deploying-microsoft-azure-webjobs/

Comment: This is looking more like the way to go, any idea what performance would be like if its run every 1 min?

Comment: Webjobs runs in background and would not incur a performance hit for your web-app. Your db on the other hand would be used by both and could be a source of performance degeneration for both web-app and webjob (although I have never experienced such issues in smaller apps. Haven't tried in high performance apps yet, but surely it could be mitigated)

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean with real time email notification but instead of using a windows service consider using [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/partners/azure/) which is an email delivery service in Azure.

**Edit:**

For the trigger, you can use Logic Apps so whenever there is a new row added in the database you can send an email, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure

Comment: What I mean is a service or job of some kind is checking the db continually to see if its time to send an email to the user.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. However if you are able to modify your busines logic to send the email on specific use-cases instead of whatching your database, I would prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

In azure we have a job scheduler which will help you to run a job or make service call which will trigger all the emails in scheduled time intervals. also you can install any windows job if you have.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), that's one of the schedulers out there I've used in quite a few projects and should be able to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks mate will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

As per the given requirement. My understanding is that you want to send email as it logged in db. I have also implication same kind of thing in my application. 
Here are the prerequisite to implement it.

a.) azure queue - To add email to queue. But if you are using database it will be ok . In that case you can save data to db and add the primary key of that table to queue message. So that we will read all required data from db based primary key.

b.) web job sdk  - This we use to send email in real time. Actually when any item is added in queue. web job sdk auto trigger an event .We write our logic to send email in that event.

c.) send grid - Then we will use to send email.

Process is like that.

When any email send

1.) It log to db same as currently on working.

2.) Make primacy key entry to storage queue.

3.) As entry added to store queue . Web job sdk event Trigger  .In this event we get that db primary key.

4.) write method to get all data from db.

5.) Use send grid to send that email.

Hope this will helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

### Azure Logic Apps

Option 1

You can create a job for each reminder your customer set, and use SendGrid, or other email actions built-in to send the reminder. The benefit of this approach is that you don't need to maintain the record of scheduled time in a separate db.

Option 2

You can have one Logic App that runs on recurrent trigger (e.g. runs every minutes), the first action is to run an SQL stored proc to get the reminders should be sent out in the next minutes, then use the built-in email actions to send the emails. The benefit of this approach is that you kept all user's data in your own db, if that's a concern.

### Other options

You may be benefit from a hybrid of services available on Azure to save cost, depending on how many jobs/what's the frequency you will see from your customers. For example, you may be able to use Azure Scheduler to schedule a job for each reminder, and the action will be to call an endpoint (the endpoint can even be another Logic Apps) to send email.